# How Golly HashTable & GC works

Tags: c++, c, garbage-collection, conways-game-of-life

I cannot really understand the GC in golly hash-life. it uses simple bucket hash but how it decides to store node and garbage collected from hash table. the comment in the script some what confusion to me.

Can any one explain its working logic.
[Golly Hash-life Program](https://github.com/jimblandy/golly/blob/master/src/hlifealgo.cpp)

Answer (score 1):

Golly uses a simple mark and sweep garbage collection strategy.  Live roots are kept in an explicit array (called "stack") that is managed by the recursive routines that find and return nodes.  When memory is exhausted, the live roots are visited depth-first to mark live nodes, then the memory blocks are scanned in address order to create a free list.

This simple policy won out over a number of alternative strategies (including reference counting and more "intelligent" disposal strategies) in our testing.

Comment: so all the live roots are kept in the stack. if need space the result are freed for new nodes